# Webform layout box not working?

Tags: webform-civicrm

Not sure if I'm missing a step here, I am trying to set up an event registration with webform. For previous set ups the layout box has worked to have two columns, but for this one it isn't. The setting doesn't seem to matter, it's showing the information as vertical instead of horizontal. I am using Drupal 7, CiviCRM 5.3.1, and webform version 7.x-4.17.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah that’s because your base theme is a bootstrap theme. Some CSS edits are required to mold the form into two columns.

Here's an example (if your node id=96:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 767px) {
  #webform-client-form-96 fieldset {
    width: 46%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Karin, is there some css that should be added to the webform-layout module to accommodate bootstrap?

Comment: It would be nice if we could find a way to generalize that CSS I referenced above

Comment: Or other CSS that unsets the width:100%